# JBoss AS 7: Logging

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I struggle a bit with JBoss AS7 and the logging. I cannot find anything related on the web despite the fact that my issue is a very general one.

The default log looks currently like this:

```
11:57:29,950 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-78) 248408930 [http--0.0.0.0-8081-78] INFO  org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
11:57:29,950 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-78) 248408930 [http--0.0.0.0-8081-78] INFO org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  - Retrying request
```

notice the [stdout], those lines where written to stout by some logging library which is used by some library and picked up by JBoss and written to the log file. This is what i want to fix.

I guess there must be a way to have an adapter which tells log4j (or any other logging framework) to log to the jboss logging subsystem?

My first idea was to remove all log4j configuration from the classpath of my project. I found one in  a library i use which did log to stdout. But this does not fix anything.

```
11:21:01,648 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
11:21:01,648 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
11:21:01,648 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

The usual error message when no appender is configured. At least i can be sure that no configuration is in the classpath anymore.

The JBoss AS documentation does not even mention this kind of scenario, how i am supposed to use 3rd party libraries when i am not able to get proper logging?

I really hope someone can help me out, any hint is appreciated!

Malax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While it's not in the question, I do assume you are attempting to use log4j with JBoss AS7. If that is true and you do need to use appenders, then you need to exclude the log4j that comes with the server and package your own version with your deployment currently. This should be changing soon once [AS7-514](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-514) is resolved. Once that feature is added, nothing will need to be done on your side.

To resolve the issue for now you first need to create a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) that should look like the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then add your own version of log4j to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory or any other place where the deployment would be able to find the library.

After that it should work just as you would expect.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for me for some reason. I fixed the XML to be well-formed (The documentation says <deployment /> is the parent-element for exclusions.) but it still get wrapped logging messages like: `09:58:04,564 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 2012-03-22 09:58:04,564 DEBUG [http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1] org.apache.http.wire: << "      </a>[\n]"`

Comment: The message will be wrapped on the console. JBoss AS 7 get's all messages logged to stdout and stderr and logs them.